# Adding a new table triggers loading all other tables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a dataset in Power BI that contains multiple tables querying from the same SQL server. Then I go to Power Query and try adding a new table which uses the same SQL server as a source, with a brand-new query (meaning it doesn't reference any other tables in the model). When I want to apply changes, Power BI triggers loading all other tables in the model, which I believe shouldn't be the case since I added only 1 table.

I tried to uncheck the box for "Auto detect new relationships after data is loaded." in Options and Settings for each table, but the issue is still there. Could you help with the possible solution?

Comment: If you're in the query editor, you may be able to use refresh instead of apply. At the report level, if it's one dataset using import, it likely will have to reload both.